# Kotlin/IDEA: How to turn off comment autocompletion when using typealias?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, autocomplete, autocommenting

Say I have a typealias

```
package server.user

typealias UserId = Int
```

Then I want to write a function in another package

```
package client.game

fun getUser(userId: UserId): User
```

When I get to

```
fun getUser(us
```

It autosuggests `userId: UserId`, and if I follow this suggestion, it adds the following

```
fun getUser(userId: UserId /* = kotlin.Int */
```

My question then is: How do I get IDEA to stop adding this comment?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. It could be my IDE settings. Are you sure the comments are real? IDEA tends to add type hints and parameter hints, but those are visual aids and not part of the code.

Comment: Just tried reproducing, and it only happens if you reference it from another package. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: still not reproducible for me

Comment: It's a bug, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20341 for updates on this problem.